# Trying To Extract Certain Records From Android Sql

Tags: android, sql, records

I am trying to extract only records that contain the field "movie" from MySql Android database. My code looks like this:

```
Class Name:MediaDbAdapter
Database table name: records
column name:KEY_TYPE

mDb.query(records, new String[] {MediaDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE},
            "KEY_TYPE = " + "'movie'",  null, null, null, null);
```

Just not working....

Comment: what exactly you want? need more clarification

Comment: mDb.query("records", new String[] {"KEY_TYPE"}, "KEY_TYPE = " + "'movie'", null, null, null, null);

Comment: Please be more specific than `Just not working` and do not put non-code items in a code block, use text block instead.  You can extract error information from logcat but please only post the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1):

```
mDb.query(records, new String[] {"KEY_TYPE"}, "KEY_TYPE = 'movie'", null, null, null, null);
```

try this

Answer (score -1):

```
db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"KEY_TYPE"}, 
            "KEY_TYPE = " + "'movie'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: mDb.query("records", new String[] {"KEY_TYPE"}, 
            "KEY_TYPE = " + "'movie'", null, null, null, null);

Comment: -1 answer is confusing. If you want to make corrections edit your post instead of using followup cmoments

Comment: i did more research, and all your answers were wrong.  thanx for the help.