# Please help me with my SQL command

Tags: android, sql, field, record

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to extract certain records from android Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162374/trying-to-extract-certain-records-from-android-sql)

This is not working:

I am trying to pull only records that contain "movie", in my "KEY_TYPE" column from my android Sql table.

This is what I have right now: mDb.query("records", new String[] {MediaDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE}, "KEY_TYPE LIKE " + "movie", null, null, null, null);

Comment: What's not working? What have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: This question has been flagged for moderation. Duplicate posting are not acceptable on [SO] please read [ask].  Please remember that there is no substitute for research and following tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"KEY_TYPE LIKE " + "movie"`

Comment: This got rid of the red lines:

Comment: mDb.query("records",
          new String[] {MediaDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE}, "type = " + "'movie'",  null, null, null, null);

Comment: But now I get, stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: I'm sorry but your going to have to rephrase your question. I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to pull only records that contain "movie", in my "KEY_TYPE" column from my android Sql table.

Comment: This is what I have right now:            mDb.query("records", new String[] {MediaDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE}, "KEY_TYPE LIKE " + "movie",  null, null, null, null);

Comment: Again, I'm sorry, but what is your question? What is the issue you are having? What is the query not doing? What errors/exceptions are you getting?